# jQuery textFill with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use [jQuery textFill](http://jquery-textfill.github.io/) to fit some dynamic text (from a database) into a div with predefined width.
My problem is that this plugin works great on a page, but i want to use it inside a twitter bootstrap modal. This doesn't seem to work. I create an example in jsFiddle. I use a div outside of the modal and a div inside. The out-of-modal div works fine. The div inside seems to have some problems :)

```
<div id="out-of-modal"> <span>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</span></div>

<div id="inside-modal"> <span>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</span></div>
```

Here is the [example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnLtsw98/2/)

Do you have any idea of what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the css selector `hide` you used here, because it has property `display:none` with `important` rule

```
 <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

and causing not the modal to show, so remove it and also for transitioning effects use css selector `fade` if you like

```
 <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

SideNote: In your fiddle you are missing key div elements of modal e.g `<div class="modal-dialog">` and `<div class="modal-content">`

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        //Modal Header, Body and Footer Comes Here
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnLtsw98/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I am really late to this thread, but I found a solution to this problem. In the actual script, there's at some point this code
 `var ourText = $(Opts.innerTag + ':visible:first', this);`
which basically tells jquery to pick the first `<span>` element inside our `<div>` that is **visible**. However, our text is obviously not visible, because it's inside the modal when the page is started, so it's hidden. There's a simple fix to this. Just go inside the library and edit that part into this and it should work perfectly:

```
var ourText = $(Opts.innerTag + ':first', this);
```